# Polymorphism and static functions

Tags: c++, polymorphism

A followup to this question : [C++ : Is there a good way to choose between 2 implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70699881/c-is-there-a-good-way-to-choose-between-2-implementations)

My goal here is that both of these classes can be called at the same runtime. So Polymorphism would be a good and easy way to go with.

I have the following diagram :
[image]

But the problem here is that each one of them(a.cpp/h and a_mockup.cpp/h) uses the singelton pattern(contains static functions) and static functions cannot be virtually declared in the baseclass.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Having static functions doesn't mean they're singletons. Singletons are evil. The solution is to never in your life touch singletons if you can help it.

Comment: The only way to implement static polymorphism is to use a [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp).

Answer (score 0):

In C++ Virtual functions are invoked during run-time, when you have a pointer/reference to an instance of a class. Static functions aren't bind to a particular instance, they're bind to a class during compile-time. Moreover, C++ doesn't have pointers-to-class functionality. So, there is no such way to solve this.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment, the CRTP is a way, to achieve static polymorphism, where those class member calls are resolved at compile time. But as a consequence everything needs to be known at compile time as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must have [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp?noredirect=1&lq=1) as your default design when aiming for static polymorphism.